# What are the structure constants for the algebra of quaternions? Show this algebra is associative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, mathematical-physics

What are the structure constants for the algebra of quaternions?  Show this algebra is associative.

How can I find the structure constants? I know that for an algebra $\mathscr{A}$ and basis $B=\{e_i\}_{i=1}^N$ for the underlying vector space, we have $e_ie_j=\sum\limits_{k=1}^N c_{ij}^k e_k$ for $c_{ij}^k\in\mathbb{C}$, which are the structure constants ($c_{ij}^k$). But I don't know how to find them for quaternions.

Ok, someone explained to me that $c_{ij}^k=c_{11}^1=\{1,0,0,0\}$, for $e_ie_j=e_ie_j$, but I still don't understand how the multiplication works. Can some explain?

Basis: $e_1=\{1,0,0,0\};e_2=\{0,1,0,0\};e_3=\{0,0,1,0\};e_4=\{0,0,0,1\}$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the quaternion algebra?

Comment: Kind of, I know that quaternion algebras have a dimension 4 over a field $F$ and that they become matrix algebras.

Comment: See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Multiplication_of_basis_elements

Comment: This question is misleading. "The" structure constants are only well-defined relative to a basis so the problem should provide such a basis.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Please consider expanding your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

As requested, I'm posting my comment as an answer.  See e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Multiplication_of_basis_elements).

The standard basis of the quaternion algebra is $\{1,i,j,k\}$, and we have
$i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$, $ij = -ji = k$, $jk = -kj = i$, $ki = -ik = j$.

Comment: To say "the" quaternion algebra is misleading because there are infinitely many (non-isomorphic) quaternion algebras. What is discussed here is Hamilton's quaternions.

Comment: "The" quaternions generally means Hamilton's quaternions.

Comment: Sure, but "the quaternion algebra" is misleading.